# Error while I install the Robot Framework

Tags: python, pip, robotframework

How can I fix and install Robot Framework.
I run the command `pip install robotframework` and get this.

```
C:\Users\shaloms>pip install robotframework
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/robotframework/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/robotframework/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/robotframework/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/robotframework/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/robotframework/
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/robotframework/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/robotframework/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
    
C:\Users\shaloms>
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?  It also looks like you have an issue accessing pypi.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open up your cmd if you are using Windows and just type:

```
python -m pip install robotframework
```

I hope it will work for you.It works for me.

Comment: I just write the same thing

Comment: @undertale if any answer works for you then consider to accept that answer by clicking on tick beside the answer which turns to green. This is the way to appreciate the person who answers your question by spending his time. This also helps other people to identify the working answer.

Comment: thanks for talking like that you are so right.Thanks Dev

Comment: I had a similar error, but was due to interference from work network security. IE, pypi.org was being blocked. Disconnected from work, then either command (pip or python -m pip) worked.